# Applying a function twice in R

Tags: r, functional-programming

I want to define a function in R that takes as argument a function and applies it twice to its arguments.

For example

```
x <- function twice (plusone 1)

3

In Haskell it is done by  twice f = \x -> f (f x)
```

.

How to do that in R?

Answer (score 7):

```
twice <- function(f, x) f(f(x))
twice(function(x) x+1, 1)
# 3
```

which may be generalised as

```
nice <- function(f, n, x) if(n==1) f(x) else Recall(f, n-1, f(x))    
nice(function(x) x+1, 2, 1)
```

Answer (score 3):

If you're coming from Haskell, you'll appreciate that currying is easy to do in R as well. This answer is also more complete than @baptiste's. See the last remark

```
repeatf <-
  function (n) function (f) function (x)
    if (n<=0) x else repeatf (n-1) (f) (f(x))

once <- repeatf (1)
twice <- repeatf (2)
thrice <- repeatf (3)

square <- function (x) x * x
once (square) (2)    # 4
twice (square) (2)   # 16
thrice (square) (2)  # 256
```

Worth noting, if `n` is a dynamic variable in your program, it could possibly be 0 or a negative number. `repeatf` will still operate in those cases

```
repeatf (0) (square) (2)  # 2
repeatf (-3) (square) (2) # 2
```

@baptiste's solution would fail with

```
nice(square, 0, 2)   # Error: evaluation nested too deeply: infinite recursion / options(expressions=)?
nice(square, -3, 2)  # Error: evaluation nested too deeply: infinite recursion / options(expressions=)?
```

Comment: obviously my version fails for n<1, but i) is that really defined/useful?; ii) I simply didn't account for those cases. `nice <- function(f, n, x) if(n<=0) x else Recall(f, n-1, f(x)) ` "fixes" it trivially. Your solution also fails in unspecified corner cases; take the example of renaming in `?Recall`.

Comment: @baptiste of course it's really useful to have a total function; one that works for all inputs of the specified type. Imagine where we call your `nice` function with variables rather than static inputs. If `n` is assigned `0` as the result of some other computation, it would break very easily. E.g., `nice(f, somefunc(), 2)` where `somefunc()` returns `0`. I don't think that's a corner case. And yes, I agree the fix is incredibly easy, so you should definitely do it.

Comment: @baptiste Can you please demonstrate how this implementation of `repeatf` breaks? I cannot see how the renaming something would cause breakage.

Comment: from `?Recall`, `repeatf2 = repeatf; rm(repeatf); repeatf2(2)(square)(1:10)`

Comment: I disagree that a function defined for positive integers should always cater for negative cases, at least without a clear motivation. It's easy to think of cases where an error should be returned, rather than silently ignored with an ill-defined value in the implementation. But that's a matter of taste probably, so let's agree to disagree. Aside from that, both methods are largely equivalent.

Comment: Haha that's a pretty obscure way to break the function for sure. I guess no function is safe if that's the kind of code we might expect to see. Lastly, I will agree with you about the negative numbers, but you code *doesn't* throw. You should pick one or the other, and your code does neither.

Comment: a less contrived and more dangerous case would be when a `repeatf2` changes the defaults arguments of a `repeatf`; one may assume it's calling itself iteratively, when it's actually calling the original function with different defaults.

Comment: There is never a need for a repeatf2 because the function is fully curried, it can be procedurally applied without having to create different references to the same thing. Anyway, this is getting pretty far off the rails. If you can avoid side-effecting in a common scenario, you should. I'll leave it at that.